PrimeVue Accordian
I'm using PrimeVue 3.5.3
I have an Accordian Component and some AccordianPanel components within that:
 <Accordion collapseIcon="pi pi-chevron-down" expandIcon="pi pi-chevron-down" :selectOnFocus="true" >
 <AccordionPanel v-for="category in data" :key="category.name" :value="category.name" @update:activeIndex="update">

I need to detect when the user clicks on an AccordianPanel to expand or collapse it but nothing I do seems to work.  I have tried adding the following events to the Accordian but none of them fire when I click on a panel
@update:activeIndex (as in the above example)
@tab-open
@tab-click

What am I doing wrong?

You are not using PrimeFaces

These events have been deprecated in v4 in favour of update:value, but they still exist, and there's no such problem in v3.
As shown in the documentation, the events belong to Accordion and not AccordionPanel. AccordionPanel is a 'dumb' wrapper for the content that delegates all logic to the container, which is a very common pattern.
It should be:
 <Accordion @update:activeIndex="update" ...>

